# Convert Alsa frames to analog values

Tags: c, alsa

I'm writing a program in C which should visualize audio. As audio source I use a microphone and the Alsa C Sound library. I take the sound frames from the Alsa library, make some transformations (Fourier analysis and similar), and then visualise them. I almost have a working program besides one exception, it seems I'm converting the Alsa-frames to doubles in a wrong way.

This is how I do it:

```
unsigned char x=getFirstByte();
signed char y=getSecondByte();
double analog_signal=(y*256+x)/32768.;
```

Now this code works, but sometimes (relatively often) I get spikes where the value of `analog_signal` is about 0.99... where it shouldn't be.

So I started printing the values of `x` and `y` when such spikes occur.
The output was quite clear: always when such a spike occurred `y` was equal to 127 and `x` was some value around 230.

My conversion is still correct in my understanding, but it seems that Alsa treats its values in a different way. So that this special value of 127 in the second byte has to be converted differently, for whatever reason?!

I don't want to believe that my microphone is broken, so could someone who has worked with the Alsa-library, kindly give me some advice on my problem.
I would also be happy with a function of the Alsa-library which does this conversion for me as I haven't found one but maybe overlooked it.

Comment: The code is correct. This sounds as if the spikes are already in the samples that the device provides.